# How to pass image location from controller to model method to store on db Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, authentication

I have the controller `store()` method that gets data from form and passes them to User model on a  method called `publish()` that publish the post on blog. My issue is that when i get the image file location I can not pass it to publish method that is stored on User model. I have tried passing like var on request, googled but no luck.

`Store()` method:

```
 public function store(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [

            'title' =>'required|max:48',
            'body'=>'required',
            'image'=>'required'
        ]);

        $post = new Post;

        $destination ='uploads';
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move($destination, $filename);
        $location=$destination.'/'.$filename;

        auth()->user()->publish(
            new post(request(['title','body', $location] ))
        );


        return redirect('/blog');
    }
}
```

and publish method on User's model:

```
    public function publish(Post $post){


    $this->post()->save($post);

}
```

To make it more clear I want variable $location to insert it on a new post method so it can get to publish method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to pass the correct **array keys and values** when create the post. Since you include `$location` in array, it will get request data from the `$location` key.

which means the value of `$location` is something like `'/path/to/image'`. So, basically your are passing the `'/path/to/image'` as the key.

Try to modify as below.

```
auth()->user()->publish(
    new post([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'body' => $request->body, 
        'location' => $location
    ])
);
```

Also make sure you already added `$fillable` in the `Post` model